# Selecting two attributes from same xml tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml of this format:

```
<xml>
    <cases total="3">
        <case>
            <ref>3</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>1</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>2</ref>
        </case>
    </cases>
</xml>
```

Now i want xsl which will print `<cases total="value">` and then sort according to the reference of each case.
Desired output:

```
<xml>
    <cases total="3">
        <case>
            <ref>1</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>2</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>2</ref>
        </case>
    </cases>
</xml>
```

My current xslt looks like this -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cases">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="case">
        <xsl:sort select="ref" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does the job but it is not showing "TOTAL" value for cases tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input XML does not have an attribute `total` for `<cases>` and the XML contains the below data as per the comment

```
<xml>
    <cases>
        <case>
            <ref>3.10</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>3.1</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>1</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>1.0</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>2.1</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>2</ref>
        </case>
    </cases>
</xml>
```

you need to make the following change to the template to add the attribute `total`

```
<xsl:template match="cases">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="total">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(case)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="case">
            <xsl:sort select="ref" datatype="text" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This gives the output as

```
<xml>
    <cases total="6">
        <case>
            <ref>1</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>1.0</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>2</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>2.1</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>3.1</ref>
        </case>
        <case>
            <ref>3.10</ref>
        </case>
    </cases>
</xml>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to sort numerically. currently it is showing 3.10 above 3.1. How to sort it numerically?

Comment: I have updated the solution to use `datatype` when sorting. However this may not give desired results for all types of data. If the value is changed to `number`, the results change. You may need a robust solution if the data contains lot of values.